# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo on Create()

Tags: java, android

I have a class login.java which i am running as main activity but when i run it the application suddenly stops and says following error. I have also pasted `activity_login.xml` and `login.java`. I am stuck here and can not understand what the issue is. Any suggestions please

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.funtube_mp4/com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0b0001 a=-1 r=0x7f0b0001}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3348)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
            at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3715)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:480)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:257)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.example.admin.funtube_mp4.Login.onCreate(Login.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2368)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2464)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5653)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/bg_login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/input_login"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_login_hint" />

        <!-- Login Button -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@color/btn_login_bg"
            android:text="@string/btn_login"
            android:textColor="@color/btn_login" />

        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLinkToRegisterScreen"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**login.java**

```
package com.example.admin.funtube_mp4;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FunTubeOperations FunTubeDBOperations;
    private DatabaseWrapper db;
    private SessionManager session;
    public static String UserName;



    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        final AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        Button reg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);
        FunTubeDBOperations = new FunTubeOperations(this);
        FunTubeDBOperations.open();

        db = new DatabaseWrapper(getApplicationContext());

        // Session manager
        session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

        // Check if user is already logged in or not
        if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
            // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Main.class);
            // session.setname(UserName);
            String n=session.getdata();
            //session.pref.getString(USER_NAME,UserName);
            intent.putExtra("name", n);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, register.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        try {


            login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
                    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
                    if (email != null && password !=null) {
                        String em=email.getText().toString();
                        String pwd=password.getText().toString();

                        UserName=  FunTubeDBOperations.loginUsers(em, pwd);


                        if(UserName!=null)
                        {
                            session.setLogin(true);
                            session.setname(UserName);

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, Main.class);

                            intent.putExtra("name", UserName);

                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid information provided!! Check your credentials or Sign up account!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill all the fields!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception er) {
            ad.setMessage(er.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**colors.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <color name="bg_login">#26AE90</color>
    <color name="bg_register">#2E3237</color>
    <color name="bg_main">#428BCA</color>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="input_login">#222222</color>
    <color name="input_login_hint">#999999</color>
    <color name="input_register">#888888</color>
    <color name="input_register_bg">#3B4148</color>
    <color name="input_register_hint">#5E6266</color>
    <color name="btn_login">#26AE90</color>
    <color name="btn_login_bg">#ECEEF1</color>
    <color name="lbl_name">#333333</color>
    <color name="btn_logut_bg">#FF6861</color>
    <color name="view_background">#E8ECfA</color>
    <color name="btn_bg">#277BEC</color>

    <color name="txt_font">#4E5572</color>
    <color name="action_bar">#1F2649</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: where is import statement for R file??

Comment: remove  `android:background="@null"`

Comment: use `AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this).create();`

Comment: @MD it didn't solved the issue. Same error

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya where should i replace this?

Comment: @tabia check your `color resources` or post `color.xml`

Comment: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): this is error so use proper color or drawble i for background or post color.xml

Clean build and run it will work well

Comment: @tabia first convert all the color Hex value in `UpperCase lattes`. It's to ugly to see

Comment: @tabia do follow #MD's advise

Comment: @MD done with your advice

Comment: Well i have solved the issue thanks for helping me

Comment: @tabia tell me the answer

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I recreated color.xml

Comment: @tabia Okay okay .Move ahead